# Text over picture with white space

Tags: diagrams, labels

I'd like to label some level curves with values that are superimposed over the level curves, creating white space around the labels so that the underlying curves appear "broken".  I figured a simple \mbox would work, but the curves pass right through .

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
\qbezier(0,0)(.5,-.5)(1,0)
\put(.45,-.3){\makebox{-8}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add color to the background of the box, with the `\colorbox` macro from the `xcolor` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
\qbezier(0,0)(.5,-.5)(1,0)
\put(.45,-.3){\colorbox{white}{-8}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added the xcolor package to my MikTeX installation, and ran the suggested code.  It compiled fine, but appears exactly as it did with \makebox. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user35910  I edited my result to show the figure that my LaTeX produces.  Is that not what you get?  Did you change the `\makebox{-8}` to `\colorbox{white}{-8}`

Comment: I don't see the figure on this page, I'm sorry.  I copied your code directly into a new latex document, and compiled.  The image appears the same as it did with \makebox.  The level curve passes through the -8.

Comment: @user35910  Oops.  It's there now.

Comment: Oh that's perfect!  But your code doesn't produce the same effect for me.  I manually installed the xcolor package and put the xcolor.sty file in my Local TeX directory, refreshed FNDB, and compiled with no errors.  What could be wrong?

Comment: I get it now!  I needed to set my Yap rendering method to Dvips rather than Pk.  Your solution is perfect.  Thank you, Steven.